# Data smoothing in three dimensions

Tags: interpolation, data

I have data with statistical fluctuations of the form $f(x_i,y_i)$ over a discrete grid. I now need the values of $f(x,y)$ also at points other than the grid points. That can be achieved by `Interpolation`. I would like to smooth the data before interpolation. In one dimension this could be done with a `MovingAverage`. How can I do this in two dimensions? Is there a method to do the smoothing in both directions, $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing even a picture of your data. In any case, there's [a number of filters](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ImageFilteringAndNeighborhoodProcessing.html) to try.

Comment: It might be good to add some example data.

Comment: If you feel comfortable with `MovingAverage[ ]` you may try `MovingAverage[{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}, 2]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: `LowpassFilter` or `GaussianFilter` might be appropriate, or you can choose your own filter kernel with `ListConvolve`.